# “I am X” vs. “X is me”

Tags: word-order, copular-verbs, predicative-complements

Is there a difference in grammaticality, meaning, or usage between the following two ways of phrasing the same statement?

> I am sure that I am the appropriate candidate for this position.

– versus

> I am sure that the appropriate candidate for this position is me.

Comment: Thanks @FumbleFingers . It would be nice if you add it as an answer, please. If it is fit for you.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the first two sentences.  The first one seems to emphasize "appropriate candidate" whilst the second one seems to stress "me". I am not a native speaker and I might be wrong, though.  The third sentence is definitely wrong.  There is no agreement between nominative pronoun and verb.

Comment: @Santosa: Please don't think I'm being rude, but I think questions like this shouldn't be "answered" on ELU (they should be asked and answered on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/))

Comment: @FumbleFingers for sure not, I don't have access to English Language Learners. Would you migrate it, please? (If you think it is necessary to migrate this question). Thanks

Comment: Since I think this is actually quite an interesting question (and I couldn’t find a duplicate, I took the liberty of rephrasing the question and getting rid of the obviously grammatically incorrect version that included “I is”. As it is now phrased, I would say the question is definitely on-topic here on ELU.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Whatever the linguistic background of the OP, I think it's a question that merits discussion. I would definitely choose the first sentence over the second; it sounds much more direct. Could I give a great explanation of why? I'm not sure. As far as I can tell, it's more a pragmatics question than an ESL one.

Comment: @dmk: The question has somewhat shifted following an edit, but your support for the first of the remaining two alternatives is really just a matter a stylistic preference (I'd say it largely depends on the *exact* context anyway).

Comment: @Santosa: I'm just an "ordinary" user, so I don't have the ability to migrate questions (but like you, I can "flag" this one with a message to the moderators to ask if they would consider migrating it). I don't understand why you "don't have access to English Language Learners" - it would surely be better for you to sign up to that site (as well as this one, if you like), because you're more likely to get answers there which are *specifically written with the problems of learners in mind.*

Comment: The two versions package their info differently. And so, different parts of it can be stressed to the listener or reader, depending on which version is used.

Comment: I guess 'is I' is more formal and sometimes better than 'is me' in the second one. In my opinion, a subject of sentence or phrase would often be what is talked in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two statements are both grammatically correct, and the difference would be a matter of style, substance, or context. For example, if one was relating about an instance where one was presenting an award, and happened to be the winner of the award he or she was presenting, one might use the latter construction: "I said, 'The best candidate for the position is [opens envelope] ... me?'". On the other hand, in a heated disputation, with someone else who is suggesting a different candidate, one can well imagine a response, "I said I am the best candidate for the position.'"

The second, using "me" has a hint of older usage about it, as it was once preferred to minimize the use of the first person singular. In some older scientific literature this even went so far as to use the third person in writing up research papers, so one usually saw "The authors found that ...", instead of the simpler "We found ...",  but this has tended to become less a consideration than formerly, and the more direct first person is preferred.